# XSLT, XPath, Using the value of current() to select and sum

Tags: xslt, xpath-2.0

I have a list of values that I need to summarize distinct item quantities. A simple version would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items xmlns:boomi="http://boomi.com/custom-function">
    <Item>
        <id>801</id>
        <qty>0</qty>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <id>802</id>
        <qty>1</qty>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <id>802</id>
        <qty>1</qty>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

I'm using the following XSLT

```
<Items>
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/Items/Item/id)" >
        <Item>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
            </id>
        </Item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Items>
```

To generate the following document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items xmlns:boomi="http://boomi.com/custom-function">
    <Item>
        <id>801</id>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <id>802</id>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

But I also need to include quantities. I've tried a few things, this being the closest, but doesn't work:

```
<Items>
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/Items/Item/id)" >
        <Item>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(/Items/Item[id=current()]/qty)" />
            </id>
        </Item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Items>
```

I think it's not working because current() is an actual node? I'm trying to get to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items xmlns:boomi="http://boomi.com/custom-function">
    <Item>
        <id>801</id>
        <qty>0</qty>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <id>802</id>
        <qty>2</qty>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Am I going about this in completely the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: Use `xsl:for-each-group`.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 0):

Here is the(a) solution using XSLT 2.0 indicated by michael.hor257k

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:boomi="http://boomi.com/custom-function">
    <xsl:template match="/">
<Items>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/Items/Item" group-by="id" >
        <Item>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            </id>
           <qty>
               <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/qty)" />
          </qty>
        </Item>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</Items>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```